# "thread apply all bt full" gives blank in GDB

Tags: linux, multithreading, debugging, gdb, slackware

I was trying to debug a multi-threaded process on a Linux server running Slackware 12 using GDB 6.6.

Once I attach and issue the command "thread apply all bt full" it comes back with nothing ( back on to the gdb prompt ).

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Is the program run as another user or root?  Are you running as root?

Comment: I did try both.
The the process is started as root but with a sudo invoking as a less privileged user.

Comment: Last guess then - are you sure it is multi-threaded?  Do you get any output just using "bt"?

Comment: Please cut/paste your entire interaction with GDB. You may also wish to upgrade your GDB to current (7.0.1) release.

Comment: @Duck, yes it is multi threaded. when using "bt" i do get backtrace for one thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try last GDB version. 7.1 or 7.2. Everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and discovered that I can fix it as follows:

1. run "bt".  this should show the backtrace of a thread, although maybe not the one you want.
2. now "cont".
3. hit ctrl+c.  I see something like "[Switching to LWP %d]"
4. hit ctrl+c again.  this breaks at the thread i want to see the backtrace of, but also seems to make "thread apply all bt full" start working.

Comment: thanks for your post; I couldnt try this anymore as I have moved away from the particular environment & that particular process that I was having trouble with. +1 for the detailed post