# gdbserver follow child

Tags: c++, linux, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug a forking process on remote host, but getting the gdbserver process end on me every time with child exit.

Tried to setting "set follow-fork-mode child" in .gdbinit, didn't help.

Is there a good solution for this one?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting that in an interactive GDB session?

Comment: This is Eclipse-RSE based session, so it's only automated.

Comment: Related, see [How do I debug the child process after fork() in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6199270/608639),  [Debugging child process after fork (follow-fork-mode child configured)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15126925/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the forking process fork more than once?  If not, you can use the --attach option to attach to the child.

Comment: Only once, but I can't figure out how to make gdbserver re-attach to forked process.

Comment: Wait for the child to fork and just attach to it.  Use a separate pair of gdb and gdbserver instances if you want to debug the parent and the child.